# How to call the microphone device and process audio data in a blazor web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor

I am writing a razor-library, one of these components' function is using microphone to record audio data then send to server.

Can someone give me a example of how to call microphone device in blazor.

Find a way to call microphone device and process audio data in Blazor web app, preferably with a sample code example.

Comment: By searching on google with the following you should get many examples: **c# record audio from microphone**